How to Configure Apache 2.4 to Allow PHP Socket.IO Connections on a Local Server?
In PHP script using phpsocket.io library I created a socket on socketio://0.0.0.0:2346.
<?php

use Workerman\Worker;
use PHPSocketIO\SocketIO;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$io = new SocketIO(2346);
$io->on('connection', function ($socket) use ($io) {
    $socket->on('message', function ($msg) use ($io) {
        $io->emit('message', $msg);
    });
});

Worker::runAll();

I am using Open Server and when starting the server through Open Server Panel (respectively through Apache) the socket does not start.
Starting using php index.php socket works and I can connect to it.
My most likely assumption is that I need to add some additional Apache server settings, but not sure. Any ideas?
Open Server 5.4.3
PHP 8.1 + phpsocket.io
Apache 2.4
I'm not sure what Apache settings I need to use to make it work, but I want to run a server and after that connect to opened socket on client.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

@ADyson thanks for the explanation and help, i'll try it tomorrow.
Question: Should i have one main index.php file with initialization code for http server stuff and also socket.io server stuff, and run it via Apache and via cmd php index.php start, or should i separate socket stuff to separate file and run this separate file via command line and keep index.php for Apache?

The socket server is entirely separate from your Web application. Having one file to run them both will not make any sense at all. Index.php in your http server will be the Home page of your website. You don't want to start a new socket server every time someone loads your page!!
